# Examples to Whole Language Typology in Turkish

Tags: linguistic-typology

I need examples to whole language typology in turkish ! The value is inconsistent for turkish language which means it has both dependent marking and head marking at the same time referring whole language typology! 2 sentences (one dependent marking one head marking) would be enough! Best regards and thanks!Check out www.wals.info chapter 25 : locus of marking : whole language typology ! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "whole language typology"?

Comment: @user6726 In the WALS, Bickel and Nichols narrowed the head- and dependent-marking distinction to two places (the clause and possessive NPs). They have a separate chapter each of these two, and a chapter ('whole language typology') that combines these two parameters.